# Counting all records from inner-join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables that has `aantal` ( `count` ) and each tables shows normal numbers or numbers with - before (example: -20) now I need to count all that records. but I don't know how I can fix that.

Sorry I am a noob in `sql`.

this is my code

The problem that i facing to is tha all records from the different tables that has column aantal not counting in total.

example: 
CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad returns 10
CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat returns -3 and -2
CSSDKMagento_30_AllocatieVoorraad returns 5
CSSDKMagento_50_AllocatieBestellingBinnen returns -1 and -1

That means that i get on return from Voorraad is 8.

I tried `count(*)` but that is not the solution. with best way I can do it?

```
SELECT 
    i.ItemCode, 
    g.warehouse,
    SUM(g.aantal) AS Voorraad,
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified 
        ELSE NULL 
    END) AS LastDate
FROM    dbo.CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad AS g 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
        ON (g.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat AS a 
        ON (a.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_30_AllocatieVoorraad AS v 
        ON (v.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_50_AllocatieBestellingBinnen AS b 
        ON (b.artcode = i.ItemCode)
WHERE 
       i.itemcode = 'TEST' 
GROUP  BY i.itemcode, 
          g.warehouse;
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: @mkRabbani that all records from the different tables that has column aantal need to count in total.

Comment: @redouan: what do you want to count exactly and do you want distinct count or u don't mind a count which is duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
SELECT SUM(Voorraad) FROM (
SELECT 
    i.ItemCode, 
    g.warehouse,
    g.aantal AS Voorraad,
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified 
        ELSE NULL 
    END) AS LastDate
FROM    dbo.CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad AS g 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
        ON (g.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat AS a 
        ON (a.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_30_AllocatieVoorraad AS v 
        ON (v.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_50_AllocatieBestellingBinnen AS b 
        ON (b.artcode = i.ItemCode)
WHERE 
       i.itemcode = 'TEST' enter code here
GROUP  BY i.itemcode, 
          g.warehouse
)src
```

Comment: i explained in the first post.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted counts of record. But it looks like you want to take the sum of the column aantal. Try using: SELECT SUM(aantal)

Comment: dtran007 thank you. but i get a error as response ( Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'aantal'. )

Comment: try: SELECT SUM(anntal) FROM ( 'insert your pasted select' ) src

Comment: Thank you Dtran007, but now this error Invalid column name 'aantal'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    i.ItemCode, 
    g.warehouse,
    SUM(g.aantal)+SUM(a.aantal)+SUM(v.aantal)+SUM(b.aantal) AS Voorraad,
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified 
        ELSE NULL 
    END) AS LastDate
FROM    dbo.CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad AS g 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
        ON (g.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat AS a 
        ON (a.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_30_AllocatieVoorraad AS v 
        ON (v.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_50_AllocatieBestellingBinnen AS b 
        ON (b.artcode = i.ItemCode)
WHERE 
       i.itemcode = 'TEST' 
GROUP  BY i.itemcode, 
          g.warehouse;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns a wrong number. i tried it first with 2 innerjoins but it returns 3 and CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad has 5 and 5 and 2 thats 12 and CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat has -3.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like following would work:

```
  WITH itemCodesScope AS
  (
    SELECT 'TEST' as target_ItemCode
  ),
  aggregated_CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad AS 
  (
    SELECT g.artcode, 
           g.warehouse,
           COUNT(g.aantal) as count_aantal,
           SUM(g.aantal) as sum_aantal,
           MAX(CASE 
              WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified 
              ELSE NULL 
           END) AS LastDate
    FROM dbo.CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad AS g
        JOIN itemCodesScope ON itemCodesScope.target_itemCode = g.artcode
    GROUP BY
           g.artcode, 
           g.warehouse
  ),
  aggregated_CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat AS 
  (
    SELECT a.artcode ,
           COUNT(a.aantal) as count_aantal,
           SUM(a.aantal) as sum_aantal
    FROM dbo.CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat AS a
        JOIN itemCodesScope ON itemCodesScope.target_itemCode = a.artcode
    GROUP BY
           a.artcode
  ),
  aggregated_CSSDKMagento_30_AllocatieVoorraad AS 
  (
    SELECT v.artcode ,
           COUNT(v.aantal) as count_aantal,
           SUM(v.aantal) as sum_aantal
    FROM dbo.CSSDKMagento_30_AllocatieVoorraad AS v
        JOIN itemCodesScope ON itemCodesScope.target_itemCode = v.artcode
    GROUP BY
           v.artcode
  ),
  aggregated_CSSDKMagento_50_AllocatieBestellingBinnen AS 
  (
    SELECT b.artcode ,
           COUNT(b.aantal) as count_aantal,
           SUM(b.aantal) as sum_aantal
    FROM dbo.CSSDKMagento_50_AllocatieBestellingBinnen AS b
        JOIN itemCodesScope ON itemCodesScope.target_itemCode = b.artcode
    GROUP BY
           b.artcode
  )
  SELECT 
    g.artcode as ItemCode, 
    g.warehouse,
    g.sum_aantal AS Voorraad,
    g.LastDate AS LastDate,
    g.sum_aantal + ISNULL(a.sum_aantal, 0) + ISNULL(v.sum_aantal, 0) + ISNULL(b.sum_aantal, 0) as sum_aantal,
    g.count_aantal + ISNULL(a.count_aantal, 0) + ISNULL(v.count_aantal, 0) + ISNULL(b.count_aantal, 0) as count_aantal
  FROM    aggregated_CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad AS g 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
        ON (g.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN itemCodesScope 
        ON itemCodesScope.target_itemCode = i.ItemCode
    LEFT JOIN aggregated_CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat AS a 
        ON (a.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    LEFT JOIN aggregated_CSSDKMagento_30_AllocatieVoorraad AS v 
        ON (v.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    LEFT JOIN aggregated_CSSDKMagento_50_AllocatieBestellingBinnen AS b 
        ON (b.artcode = i.ItemCode)
```

**Explanation**

[SQL-joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) produce [Cartesian Products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), which most probably led to unexpected results in the initial query. Here there are 4 'amount'-tables which are connected via Joins with conditions 'ON (b.artcode = i.ItemCode)', so if there any table contains several records per condition output will contain several records per ItemCode.

Let's say there are 9 records in a-table with a.artcode per single i.ItemCode, so there is a one-to-many relation. And let's say there is 1 record in b-table per single i.ItemCode. Output of Join will have 9 a.aantal records, but 9 repeated b.aantal records as well. Given that there is an aggregation (group by) it will effect that SUM(b.aantal) in this Joins-query will produce 9-time more than sum(b.aantal) in standalone query on b-table only.

Cartesian Product could be seen more easily, if run the initial query without aggregation:

```
SELECT *
FROM    dbo.CSSDKMagento_10_Plankvoorraad AS g 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
        ON (g.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_20_GeenAllocatieWelFiat AS a 
        ON (a.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_30_AllocatieVoorraad AS v 
        ON (v.artcode = i.ItemCode)
    INNER JOIN dbo.CSSDKMagento_50_AllocatieBestellingBinnen AS b 
        ON (b.artcode = i.ItemCode)
WHERE 
       i.itemcode = 'TEST'
```

The fixture was: doing group by aggregation before making joins. Most convenient way for this imho is [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression). With CTE I created 4 temporary tables with aggregates per ItemCode, so temporary tables are one-to-one per ItemCode. Then Joins on one-to-one produce just single output row per ItemCode.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This works!! can you pls tell me what it all does?

Comment: @redouan, added an explanation. Also if there is an answer solves your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @redouan, instruction is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work